# PHP add a calculation to results, push to results array, sort, then print

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have a SQL database that is being queried and needs to be sorted by a calculation based off of user input, then sorted by said calculation, then printed out.

Weird, I know.

So, with the help of the oracle known as Google, I came up with the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$buffer = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$vars;
$calc1 = [[equation]];
$calc2 = [[equation]];
$calc3 = [[equation]];
$calc4 = [[equation]];

$row['calc1'] = $calc1;
$row['calc2'] = $calc2;
$row['calc3'] = $calc3;
$row['calc4'] = $calc4;

$buffer[] = $row;
}

print "<table border='1px' cellpadding='4px' cellspacing='0'><tr><th>TABLE HEADERS</th></tr>";
foreach($buffer as $row){
    print "<tr><td>";
print $row['rows....'];

print "</tr>";

}
unset($buffer, $row);
print "</table>";
mysql_close();
```

Obviously a lot more complex, but the code is proprietary at the moment. I will have hundreds of entries, and the calculation is as follows:

`round((((($b1 / $b2) * ($bcMix * $pVm)) + (($c1 / $c2) * ((1 - ($bcMix * .01)) * $pVm)) * 12)  * 5) + $pP, 2);`

I also want to sort the result by two criteria: the calculation itself as well as a numerical database entry - both low to high. `usort` is causing my site to crash (for whatever reason):

```
usort($buffer, function($a, $b){
 return $a['tcoy1'] < $b['tcoy1']; 
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: array_push expects an array to push to, and what to push. Also, are you sure you can't sort it purely in SQL?

Comment: The sorted criteria is based on user input - so it would need to be calculated first, then sorted. Can SQL do good calculations? $row is an array, whenever I do `var_dump($row)` it prints `array(...`.

Comment: @Christopher: Show us the calculations. Yes, MySQL can do calculations. Depending on how complex they are and how many records you have, it may or may not be better to do them in SQL vs PHP.

Comment: @Mark I hav edited my question for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Try fetch to buffer:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$buffer = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $vars;

    $calc1 = [[equation]];
    $calc2 = [[equation]];
    $calc3 = [[equation]];
    $calc4 = [[equation]];

    $row['calc1'] = $calc1;
    $row['calc2'] = $calc2;
    $row['calc3'] = $calc3;
    $row['calc4'] = $calc4;

    $buffer[] = $row;
}

// sort $buffer by 'calc1' DESC:
usort($buffer, function($a, $b){ return $a['calc1'] < $b['calc1']; });

print "<table border='1px' cellpadding='4px' cellspacing='0'><tr><th>TABLE HEADERS</th></tr>";

foreach($buffer as $row){
    print "<tr><td>";
    print $row['rows....'];
    print "</td></tr>";
}

unset($buffer, $row);

print "</table>";
mysql_close();
```

You have inappropirate use of [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). Check the manual. Still, I don't think it even needed there.

***P.S.:*** [`php_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension is [***deprecated***](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`php_mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`php_pdo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: The sorting would be lowest to highest on Calc1 then by a database entry Var1.

Comment: @Christopher , strange... Try it might because of anonimous function. Try apply callback [old fashion way](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: -- Nevermind -- It worked, now it isn't displaying any results.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_multisort()` or `usort()` with a custom comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing any complex calculations you're better off doing them in `PHP` and here's why:

1. There is support for most of the math types in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php), in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html) not as many.
2. In PHP you can handle a failed equation with a response, if you're doing them on a database server you have to pull the error, analyse and determine what happened.
3. Databases are designed for storing data and PHP is a programming language for running programs (and equations).
4. You can store the equations in a secure database table and then run them via PHP at will.

Anything with `MySQL` in the name is for the database only. You're doing a few extra things. I'm assuming that because you're pulling a query(although you don't show the query) that you're storing the equations in the database.

When you use `mysqli_fetch_array()` you're pulling the result from the database into an array already, so no need to call it twice. Anything pulled in a `while()` statement is going to live for the life of the while unless it's loaded into an existing var or array.

Storing the queries in the database is the tricky bit because you can store a `$` character with single quotes and have it be a literal character you can use later for evaluation.

```
<?php
//If the vars are set then we're ready for processing
if(!empty($_POST['var1'])&&!empty($_POST['var2'])){

$query = 'select * from equations';
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

//Create the array for storing the equations
$equations = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $equation = $row['id'];
    //store the equations into the array
    $equations[$id]=$equation;
}

//Do some sort of check here... I'm expecting a number
if(is_numeric($_POST['var1'])){
    $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
} else {
//set a default (not 0) 
    $var1 = 1;  
}

//Do some sort of check here... I'm expecting another number
if(is_numeric($_POST['var2'])){
    $var2 = $_POST['var2'];
} else {
//set a default (not 0) 
    $var2 = 1;  
}

//Cool little function for doing equations with 2 vars being passed.
function doEquation($eq,$var1,$var2){
//eg. $eq = '$var1+$var2';
    eval("\$answer=\"$eq\";");
    return $answer;
}

$code = "<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<body>\n";
$code .= "<table style='padding:4px;border:none;'><tr><th>Table Header</th></tr>";

foreach($equations as $id=>$eq){
    $answer = doEquation($eq,$var1,$var2);      
    $code .= "<tr><td>Answer $id = $answer</td></tr>\n";    

}

$code .= "</table>";
$code .= "</body></html>";
} else {
//No vars set we can show them the form for the calculations.

$code = "<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<body>\n";
$code .= "<form method='post'>";
$code .= "Enter Var1<br>";
$code .= "<input type='number' name='var1' value='1' />";
$code .= "Enter Var2<br>";
$code .= "<input type='number' name='var2' value='1' />";
$code .= "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Calculate' />";
$code .= "</form>"; 
$code .= "</body></html>";
}

print $code;

?>
```

You'll want to be careful with some of the calculations. You have to type and check all of the incoming variables. For instance you can't divide by 0 because it will throw an error. Also it is possible to load a very complicated equation with enough info to crash a server. Remember anything coming into the server that will be parsed needs to be filtered and checked against what you're expecting. You don't want to use `echo` commands and have someone start throwing `$_SERVER` vars to the screen.

Also because in my example we're using `eval()` you want to make sure this can't perform any additional equations or functions submitted by the user. So `strip_tags()` and so forth as necessary. Since my example was expecting a number, I'm checking to see if it `is_numeric`.

Comment: You might have misunderstood... I don't want to put the calculations into the database, I just want to do a calculation based off of user input AND database entries, then use the result to sort the results and also print them out. Hard to show with proprietary code...

Comment: I made 8 proprietary calculators a few weeks ago for calculating welding times on industrial pipes. It was much easier to do them in PHP.

Comment: Most of the other calculators I make are statistical user tracking apps and usually they can be written in `MySQL`, although it's roughly the same speed using `PHP` or `MySQL` in that regard.

Comment: Is there a real difference between each method? Both are executed on the server, so it won't effect end user performance either way.

Comment: Depending on how the vars are stored it could be more intensive to process the file on the database server. You submit vars to PHP, it forwards vars to MySQL, MySQL performs a query using a Join and returns the values as an array back to PHP, PHP processes array and displays vars in content. If the query fails and you have to print out the error for debugging you've printed your equations in HTML (visible to all).

Comment: Otherwise you submit vars to PHP. PHP pulls equations with a simple query. PHP evaluates the equations and returns the values in content. I think this method is simpler. If you're concerned about someone seeing the proprietary equations you can lock down the server and `base64_encode` the equations for transferring from the database. It's all still server side, nobody sees the equations. Unlike Javascript.

Comment: MySQL wouldn't need to do a join if you're not storing the equations in the server. If that's the case there is no need to use MySQL at all because you're only passing equations as queries to the MySQL server from PHP. You could just as easily do the queries in PHP on the web server itself.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: Only if you're debugging like a noob. You should have a development server; there's no need to spit out debug info on a live server. `base64_encode` does just about nothing to protect your equations; it's trivially decoded and easily recognizable. Moreover, it's not necessary if it doesn't leave the server.

Comment: @Mark `base64_encode` would make it so the equations weren't easily text-readable by anyone who glanced at the database (a non-programmer). You could double encode them for that matter. Anyone who has access to the code and the database can see everything because it's all spelled out. He's using `die(mysql_error())`; Let's hope that's only on the dev server. If he's using it on a production box then bots would be all over it if he's using an open source browser or OpenDNS to get to a remote server.